# How to update a property of an array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to change the state of a property("active") of an array of objects to false or true depending on which function should I call.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59fc98974aceec3e70a18715"),
    "name": "Mostaganem",
    "destinations": [
        {
            "active": true,
            "seaport": ObjectId("59fc98594aceec3e70a18712")
        },
        {
            "active": false,
            "seaport": ObjectId("59fc98884aceec3e70a18714")
        }
    ]
}
```

If I execute this petition on robo3T, it changes, but when I call by the api to this function it does not change, could you help me?

```
async deactivate(id) {
    /* await this.update(
        { destinations: { $elemMatch: { seaport: id } } }, 
        { $set: { 'destinations.$.active': false } }, 
        { multi: true }); */
    await this.update({ '_id': id }, { $set: { 'destinations.$[].active':    false } });
}


async deactivate(id) {
    // await this.update({ destinations: { $elemMatch: { seaport: id } } // }, {    $set: { 'destinations.$.active': false } }, { multi: true });
    await this.update({ '_id': id }, { $set: { 'destinations.$[].active': false } });
},
```

Comment: Can you just add **{upsert:false,multi:true}** to end of update

Comment: In your example, what thoes `this` in `this.update`? Is it the model or the schema or a document? Can you post your Schema?

Comment: With this I'm reffering to the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own available scenario:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("539b6b5dc7ac9bc0316e3d61")
"permissions" : {
        "projects" : [
            {
                "edit" : true,
                "view" : true,
                "projectId" : ObjectId("532708cba8ed009019151b13"),
            }
        ],
}
```

To update the view key in permissions of the project:

```
db.users.update({ _id: ObjectId("539b6b5dc7ac9bc0316e3d61"), 'permissions.projects.projectId': ObjectId("532708cba8ed009019151b13") }, { $set: {'permissions.initiatives.$.view': false }})
```

The dollar($) points to the object projects array whose id we entered in query and update the particular object in array.